# Solving a system of 5 nonlinear equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm having difficulty using the fsolve function to solve a set of 5 equations in Matlab.

Here are the 5 equations:

y = a + d + e

y + x = c + d + 2e

2x = 4a + 2b + 2c

k1 = (d * b^3 / (a * c) ) * ((P/Pref)/(a+b+c+d+e))^2

k2 = b*e/(d*c)

y,x,k1,k2,P,Pref are all parameters that I set, but would like to leave them in the function so that I can change them quickly in my code to find new answers. a,b,c,d,e are the variables that I'd like to solve for (they are compositions of a reaction equilibrium equation)

I tried to hard code the parameters in the function, but that didn't work. I'm just not sure what to do. Every thing I change creates a new error. The most common is that the data type has to be "double".

Edit: adding code

first the function:

```
function F = myfun(Q,I)
a = Q(1);
b = Q(2);
c = Q(3);
d = Q(4);
e = Q(5);
x = I(1);
y = I(2);
k1 = I(3);
k2 = I(4);
P = I(5);
Pref = I(6);
F(1) = a + d + e - y;
F(2) = c + d + 2*e - y - x;
F(3) = 4*a + 2*b + 2*c - 2*x;
F(4) = ((d * b^3)/(a*c))*((P/Pref)/(a+b+c+d+e))^2 - k1;
F(5) = (b*e)/(c*d);
```

next is the program:

```
%Q = [a,b,c,d,e]
%I = [x,y,k1,k2,P,Pref]
%The values for the inputs will be changed to vary the output
%Inputs:
x=5;
y=1;
k1=5;
Pref=1;
P=1;
k2=-0.01;
syms K
k1 = solve(log10(k1) - k1);
syms L
k2 = solve(log10(k2) - k2);
x = double(x);
y = double(y);
Pref = double(Pref);
P = double(P);
k1 = double(k1);
k2 = double(k2);

%Solving:
I = [x,y,k1,k2,P,Pref];
q = [0,0,0,0,0]; %initial guess
Q = fsolve(@myfun,[q,I])
```

when I run this, these errors comes up:

```
Error using myfun (line 7)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in fsolve (line 218)
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in Coal (line 27)
Q = fsolve(@myfun,[q,I])

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Edit 2: changed the fsolve line, but still got errors:

```
Error using trustnleqn (line 28)
Objective function is returning undefined values at initial point. FSOLVE cannot continue.

Error in fsolve (line 376)
    [x,FVAL,JACOB,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,msgData]=...

Error in Coal (line 27)
fsolve(@(q) myfun(q,I),q)
```

Edit3: changed a couple parameters and the initial guess, I am now getting an answer, but it also comes up with this:

```
Solver stopped prematurely.

fsolve stopped because it exceeded the function evaluation limit,
options.MaxFunEvals = 500 (the default value).


ans =

    0.0000    2.2174    3.7473    1.4401    3.8845
```

how can I get it to not stop prematurely?

Comment: Can you show what code you have written?

Comment: @David , I added the code.

Comment: `fsolve` only works on functions with one input, even if it's a vector, so try `fsolve(@(q) myfun(q,I),q)` instead.

Comment: @David, I changed the code and there is a new error.

Comment: Might be in calculating `F(4)` and `F(5)`, if `a=0`, `c=0`, `d=0` or `a+b+c+d+e=0` you will have division by zero, and since your initial guess is `a=b=c=d=e=0`, I'd guess that might be the issue.

Comment: Maybe try splitting into two problems, one where `b=0` and one where `e=0`, (`F(5)` means one of these has to be true. I'd imagine they will give you two different classes of solutions, so reducing the number of equations and variable by one, and solving twice, might work better.

Comment: If you can provide a derivative for your function, i.e. return not only F, but g, which is the gradient of f with respect to parameters, you should get better performance with the numerical solvers.

Comment: How confident are you that this system has a solution, **and** that the solution is unique?  Solvers won't converge if the system is under-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Re: how can I get it to not stop prematurely?

Pass non-default options in your call to fsolve.

Refer to the signature, fsolve(myfun,q,options) here,
http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

And read about creating the options using optimoptions here,
http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html

You should be able to get it to "not stop prematurely" by increasing the values of convergence criteria such as TolFun and TolX.

However, it's advisable to read up on the underlying algorithms you're relying upon to perform this numerical solution here,
 (EDIT: I tried to fix non-linky links, but I'm not allowed to provide more than two ... Boo) www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#moreabout

The error you received simply indicates that after 500 function evaluations the algorithm has not yet converged on an acceptable solution conforming to the default solver options. Just increasing MaxFunEvals may allow the algorithm extra iterations needed to converge within default tolerances. For example,

```
options = optimoptions('MaxFunEvals',1000); % try something bigger than 500
fsolve(@(q) myfun(q,I),q,options);
```